# ffmpeg generated videos crashes on iOS

Tags: php, ios, ffmpeg

I have a PHP based web page where users can upload their images and those are later turned into a mp4 video using ffmpeg. The web server where the videos are generated, is hosted on CentOS. The process is like this:

1) Convert each image to a few seconds long mp4 video
`ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i step1.jpg -c:v libx264 -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -t 5 -pix_fmt yuv420p step1.mp4`

2) Convert each video to mpg for merging
`ffmpeg -y -i step1.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts step1.mpg`
(these 2 steps are repeated for each image that is uploaded)

3)Finally - merge all steps together to make one mp4 video
`ffmpeg -y -i "concat:step1.mpg|step2.mpg|step3.mpg" -c copy video.mp4`

The video always works on Windows computers, but when player on Apple iOS, it crashes after the first merge. Either the video player displays error, or the video just is not played correctly. What could possibly be the issue? Thanks.

Comment: There are a lot of codec specific parameters and mp4 layout issues that could cause this. Maybe try VLC on Mac OS to see if you can reproduce this on a player with extensive logging.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but you might consider using ffmpeg's [concat demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20(join,%20merge)%20media%20files#demuxer), so you wouldn't need to create intermediate files (and would need one less ffmpeg invocation).